# devServer doent work for multiply entries in webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to do react app with two diferent entries. One for admin and another for user.
this is my webpack.config

```
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
require('dotenv').config();
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    const isDevelopment =
        process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && argv.mode !== 'production';
    console.log('isDevelopment', isDevelopment);
    return {
        mode: isDevelopment ? 'development' : 'production',
        devtool: isDevelopment ? 'inline-cheap-source-map' : false,
        target: 'web',
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
                Auth: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/auth'),
                Editor: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/editor'),
                Ui: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/ui'),
                UserCabinet: path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    'src/components/userCabinet'
                ),
                Context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/context'),
                Services: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/services'),
                Utils: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils'),
            },
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                chunks: ['index'],
                template: 'public/index.html',
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                chunks: ['admin'],
                filename: 'admin/index.html',
                template: 'public/admin.html',
            }),
            isDevelopment && new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
            new Dotenv(),
            new CopyPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    { from: './src/manifest.json', to: '' },
                    { from: './src/service-worker.js', to: '' },
                    { from: './src/offline.html', to: '' },
                ],
            }),
        ].filter(Boolean),
        entry: {
            index: './src/index.js',
            admin: './src/admin.js',
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: isDevelopment
                ? '[name]__[contenthash:4].js'
                : '[contenthash].js',
            clean: true,
        },
        optimization: {
            runtimeChunk: { name: 'runtime' },
        },
        performance: {
            hints: false,
        },
        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: {
                disableDotRule: true,
                rewrites: [{ from: /^\/admin\/.*$/, to: 'admin.html' }],
            },
            static: {
                directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
                serveIndex: true,
                watch: true,
            },
            hot: true,
        },
        stats: 'errors-warnings',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
                            options: {
                                plugins: [
                                    isDevelopment &&
                                        require.resolve('react-refresh/babel'),
                                ].filter(Boolean),
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                modules: {
                                    localIdentName: '[local]',
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                modules: {
                                    localIdentName: isDevelopment
                                        ? '[name].[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                                        : '[hash]',
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                sassOptions: {
                                    includePaths: [
                                        path.join(__dirname, 'src/styles'),
                                    ],
                                },
                                additionalData: `@import "_variables.scss";`,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff2)$/,
                    type: 'asset',
                },
            ],
        },
    };
};
```

And in only works for 
for all another routes it shows Cannot GET {path}.

As I understoot I have a problem with devServer, because it not working write for second app. Because browser doesnt see admin.html and admin.js

DO you have any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake.
It was because I write wrong rewrites for DevServer.
So the write way is :  rewrites: [{ from: /^/admin/.*$/, to: 'admin/index.html' }],

Comment: also change output filename : '[name].js'

Answer (score 0):

This works with WEBPACK 5

```
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
require('dotenv').config();
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    const isDevelopment =
        process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && argv.mode !== 'production';
    console.log('isDevelopment', isDevelopment);
    return {
        mode: isDevelopment ? 'development' : 'production',
        devtool: isDevelopment ? 'inline-cheap-source-map' : false,
        target: 'web',
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
                Auth: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/auth'),
                Editor: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/editor'),
                Ui: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/ui'),
                UserCabinet: path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    'src/components/userCabinet'
                ),
                Context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/context'),
                Services: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/services'),
                Utils: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils'),
            },
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                chunks: ['index'],
                template: 'public/index.html',
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                chunks: ['admin'],
                filename: 'admin/index.html',
                template: 'public/admin.html',
            }),
            isDevelopment && new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
            new Dotenv(),
            new CopyPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    { from: './src/manifest.json', to: '' },
                    { from: './src/service-worker.js', to: '' },
                    { from: './src/offline.html', to: '' },
                    {
                        from: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
                        to: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
                        toType: 'dir',
                        noErrorOnMissing: true,
                        globOptions: {
                            ignore: [
                                '**/.DS_Store',
                                '**/index.html',
                                '**/admin.html',
                            ],
                        },
                        info: {
                            minimized: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }),
        ].filter(Boolean),
        entry: {
            index: './src/index.js',
            admin: './src/admin.js',
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: isDevelopment ? '[name].js' : '[contenthash].js',
            clean: {
                keep: /index\.html/,
            },
        },
        optimization: {
            runtimeChunk: { name: 'runtime' },
        },
        performance: {
            hints: false,
        },
        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: {
                disableDotRule: true,
                rewrites: [{ from: /^\/admin\/.*$/, to: '/admin/index.html' }],
            },
            static: false,
            hot: true,
        },
        stats: 'errors-warnings',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
                            options: {
                                plugins: [
                                    isDevelopment &&
                                        require.resolve('react-refresh/babel'),
                                ].filter(Boolean),
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                modules: {
                                    localIdentName: '[local]',
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                modules: {
                                    localIdentName: isDevelopment
                                        ? '[name].[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                                        : '[hash]',
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                sassOptions: {
                                    includePaths: [
                                        path.join(__dirname, 'src/styles'),
                                    ],
                                },
                                additionalData: `@import "_variables.scss";`,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff2)$/,
                    type: 'asset',
                },
            ],
        },
    };
};
```